# Term reference list with a field for extra information

Tags: entities, taxonomy-terms

For a site I'm working on I have a functionality in mind that I simply cannot wrap my head around as to how I would set it up.
When creating content of a specific content type I want to have the option to select multiple items using checkboxes from a list of about 30 items, and have the option to add a short piece of text (less than 20 characters) to each of these items if I want to.

Currently I have no real idea on how to set this up. I'm planning on adding the 30 or so items to a vocabulary so I can easily reference them, but how would I be able to select these items and add the piece of text so it's linked to these items as well?

Basically what I'm looking for is the following:
[image]

I hope someone is able to shed some light on this for me, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at the [Double Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/double_field) module

Comment: I just tried out the Double Field module but sadly that only offers entry for 1 item using a select field or checkbox. I want to be able to select multiple items from my list of terms. I expanded my original question with more information and an image to better show what I'm looking for.

Comment: Additionally You can use [Field Group module](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group) to make all of them under a roof.

Comment: That might be what I end up doing if I can't find a proper solution. I was hoping I wouldn't have to add 30 Double Fields as that's going to be a mess to maintain. Thanks for the help though! If anyone else can pitch in feel free to do so.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can achieve that in two ways.

Using the combination of [Double Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/double_field) and [Field group](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group) modules.

> Use "Double field" for to make list of checkbox and textfields, and Field Group to make all of them a Group.

There is another option to achieve this. Try the [Composed Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/composed_field) module

> Composed Field is an implementation of core's Field UI that allows you to split a single field into as many sub-fields as you like.

This seems very close to your requirement. I've used this one of my project and working fine.